# Print multiple choice grid

Tags: forms, grid

I am constructing a Google Form questionnaire. One of the questions that I apply is the multiple-choice grid. When I want to print the questionnaire, the multiple-choice grid questions become "shaky". I do not know how to adjust. Can anyone help me with this issue?

This is the issue that I am facing
[image: issue screenshot]

Comment: Post the code you have tried.